# Chrome extension: inject user-specified local CSS file to the page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to allow users add and inject a local CSS file to a page. Is there a way to do it or I only limited to files shipped with the extension itself?

Comment: Use a file input in your options/popup page to read the contents of the file, store it in chrome.storage.local, then add to the page using chrome.tabs.insertCSS inside chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted in the background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, would I be able to somehow track changes this way? In other words, would that save file path or rather file contents?

Comment: No. You'll have to ask the user to specify the file:// path, allow file access for your extension and then poll this URL periodically, which is quite wasteful.